# mysql time select where compare

Tags: mysql, sql

mysql datetime select problem.

my table check_time:

```
count = 1
start = 23:57:45
end = 00:02:10

count = 2
start = 00:02:45
end = 00:07:10
```

i tried this query:

```
select count 
from check_time 
where start <= DATE_FORMAT(now(), '%H:%i:%s') 
  and end >= DATE_FORMAT(now(), '%H:%i:%s');
```

i want the now() = "23:57:45" between "00:02:10" select -> count = 1

not working on count 1 only.

but working perfectly other count 2~100..

sorry for my bad english.

Comment: You need to explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: i want the now() = "23:57:45" between "00:02:10" select -> count = 1

Comment: What is the actual data type you have used for columns `start` and `end`? Are these "time" columns? or "varchar" columns? provide DDL of the table

Comment: start and end is “time” columns!

Answer (score 0):

A great deal depends on how you have actually defined the columns `start` and `end`. I have assumed they are "time" columns in the following.

Also note that to avoid the problem of using the server time which I could not control I have used @curtime but in your code **you should use CURTIME() instead**. See the demonstration demonstration at [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6ae160/1)

```
CREATE TABLE check_time
    (`count` int, `start` time, `end` time)
;

INSERT INTO check_time
    (`count`, `start`, `end`)
VALUES
    (1, '23:57:45', '00:02:10'),
    (2, '00:02:45', '00:07:10')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
set @curtime:= cast('23:57:45' as time)
select
*
, @curtime
from check_time
where (
        (`start` < `end` and @curtime between `start` and `end`)
     OR (`start` > `end` and
              (@curtime between `start` and cast('24:00:00' as time) ) 
           OR (@curtime between cast('00:00:00' as time) and `end` )
           )
      )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6ae160/1/1)**:

```
| count |    start |      end | @curtime |
|-------|----------|----------|----------|
|     1 | 23:57:45 | 00:02:10 | 23:57:45 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
set @curtime:= cast('00:02:45' as time)
select
*
, @curtime
from check_time
where (
        (`start` < `end` and @curtime between `start` and `end`)
     OR (`start` > `end` and
              (@curtime between `start` and cast('24:00:00' as time) ) 
           OR (@curtime between cast('00:00:00' as time) and `end` )
           )
      )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6ae160/1/3)**:

```
| count |    start |      end | @curtime |
|-------|----------|----------|----------|
|     2 | 00:02:45 | 00:07:10 | 00:02:45 |
```

Comment: I am going to have to reconsider this answer as I have realized that simply flipping the start/end to end/start isn't accurate

Comment: I replaced my original with the version now seen above (using variable  @curtime)